# Usage of 全部束 and かなう

Tags: meaning, parsing

> 同級生の男の子を**全部束にしてもかなわない**ほど頻繁にハリーは散髪させられたが、...
>   Harry was made to get a haircut so often that *even if you made the boys in his class into a complete bundle it would not rival it*

The meaning is clear (I think): "Harry was made to get a hair cut more often than the rest of his classmates put together", but there's no way I could have made this sentence myself.

There are two parts that are confusing me:

1. I can't find 全部束 in the dictionary (bilingual or monolingual). It doesn't have that many hits on Google either. Is this a common word/compound? Some other examples would help, please.
2. I'm not comfortable with the use of the verb かなう. "To rival" implies some sort of competition. I feel I had to stretch the meaning a bit to get the English translation. Again, I think some similar examples of this usage may help me to feel happier about this verb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. 全部 here works as an adverb. It's functioning the same way as in...

> 髪を**全部**まとめる
>   ケーキを**全部**食べる

「[束]{たば}にする」 means "put ~~ together". This 束 is like "a group/bunch (of people)". cf: 「束になる」

> 子供たちが**束になって**掛かってきた。
>   The children「attacked me **in a group** [｟口｠ganged up on me].
>   (プログレッシブ和英中辞典)

2. I think かなう ([敵]{かな}う) here means "match" "equal" or "compare" (「[匹敵]{ひってき}する」).

> 彼にはかなわない。 I am no match for him.
>   彼にかなう者はいない。 No one can match him. / He has no equal/rival.

---

> 同級生の男の子を全部束にしてもかなわないほど頻繁にハリーは散髪させられたが...
>   I'm not comfortable with the use of the verb かなう. "To rival" implies some sort of competition.

意味は分かるんですけど、私も、ちょっと変な文だなっていう感じがします。「散髪の頻度」で、人に「かなう」とか「かなわない」とか、あんまり言わないと思うので・・・

Comment: Part 1 makes perfect sense, thanks. I'm still not sure about part two. Your two examples still imply competition. It sounds like a rather poetic way to talk about the frequency of a hair cut.

Comment: Ah. Just seen your edit. It seems you think it's a bit strange too.

Comment: `男の子を全部束にしてもかなわない` まで読むと、「ケンカとか、腕力の話かな？」って思ってしまいますよね・・・ 「[及]{およ}ばないほど...」とかのほうが自然かも、っていう気もします、「同級生の男子全員の回数を合わせても及ばないほど...」とかどうですかね・・